# Wheat Farming Problem Derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am currently learning derrivatvies in our class and i am faced with this problem at hand.

> Wheat farmer is converting to corn because he believes that corn is a
>   more lucrative crop. It is not feasible for him to convert all his
>   acreage to corn at once. He is farming 500 acres of corn in the
>   current year and is increasing that number by 50 acres per year. As he
>   becomes more experienced in growing corn, his output increases. He
>   currently harvests 130 bushels of corn by acre, but the yield is
>   increasing by 5 bushels per acre per ear. When both the increasing
>   acreage and the increasing yield are considered, how rapidly is the
>   total number of bushels of corn increasing per year.

Well what i did was i know the next year he has $130 + 5$ or $135$ bushels per acre since it increases $5$ acres per year. And then he adds $50$ acres per year. So $50 * 135$ should give you the number of bushels of corn increasing per year.. Which is $6750$ bushels per year.

But when i look on answer key on my text book the answer is $9000$ bushels per year. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(n)$ denote the number of acres devoted to corn in year $n$.  We have $$f(n)=500+50n$$

Let $g(n)$ denote the yield, per acre, in year $n$.  We have $$g(n)=130 +5n$$

It follows that the $t(n)$, the number of bushels of corn harvested in year $n$, is $$t(n)=f(n)\times g(n)=\left(500+50n\right)\times \left(135+5n\right)$$

We deduce that $$t'(n)=f'(n)g(n)+f(n)g'(n)=50g(n)+5f(n)$$

Thus $$t'(0)=50\times 130+5\times 500=9000$$

Comment: I dont understand why you used 0 as your input in your last equation. Would you mind explaining that please?

Comment: Well, frankly, I used it because it gives the desired answer.  Of course, in general, the answer is a function of $n$ but, given the answer, I suppose they wanted the initial rate of increase.  In general, we get $t'(n)=9000+500n$.

Comment: Ohh okay. So basically when the years grow , the rate of increase grows with it since 5 bushels per acre now become 10 bushels per acre?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  In general, we get $t'(n)=9000+500n$.  Of course, I am assuming that the growth is linear, as described in my post.  You could have intended something else (but linear growth is a pretty standard way to model things like this).

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Units are always important because they tell you if your reasoning has been correct.

The number of acres is: 
$$ a(y) = 500 \text{acres}  + 50\text{(acres / year)}\times y, $$

where $y$ is the number of years. Clearly $y$ is measured in years, and thus $a$ is measured in acres, as it should!

The total number of bushes is:

$$  b(a, y) = [130 \text{(bushels / acre)} + 5 \text{(bushels / (acre*year))}\times y]\times a.  $$

We see that the equations are correct because $b$ is measured in bushels. Continuing we drop the units and we end up with:

$$b(y) = (130 + 5y)\overbrace{(500 + 50y)}^{a(y)}.$$

From here you derive and evaluate in the present, i.e. $y=0$. However the question should be: how rapidly is the total number of bushels of corn increasing per year currently?